# How to find the count of a div tag in html file in ios?

Tags: javascript, html, ios

I have a string data of html content in the webview.That is the following code,

```
NSString *htmlContent = [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.innerHTML"];
```

In this, there is a `div class = 'slide'`. How to find the count of all `div class= slide` in ios.

Please make a reply.

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementByClassName(".slide").length();
```

Or in some cases `.count()`

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is using `NSScanner` and you can use Hpple too.

```
 NSString *url = nil;
    NSString *htmlString = ...
    NSScanner *theScanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:htmlString];
    // find start of DIV tag
    [theScanner scanUpToString:@"<div class='Slide'" intoString:nil];
```

And then you can handle the count according to your requirement.
**UPDATED:**

To count number of occurrences of yourString you can use this:

```
NSArray *arr = [@"I am a boy but I am not having dinner." componentsSeparatedByString:@"I"];
    NSLog(@"yourAnswer %d", [arr count]-1);
```

Your answer will be count of array minus 1.

Comment: thanks for your immediate reply.But how can i separate the count from the NSScanner?Please give the answer fully.

Answer (score 1):

```
var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('slide');

alert (divs.length);
```

Comment: how can i use the code in ios?How to include the jQuery in ios?